# Out Of Memory: GC overhead limit exceeded, after jboss upgraded from 6 to 7

Tags: java-8, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, spring-4

We have a legacy application which is build using spring3 and java 7 and it was running on Jboss 6. Recently we have upgraded the jboss server from version 6 to version 7.1.3 with spring version from 3.0 to 4.3.1 and java from Oracle 1.7.0_60-b19 to Open java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.191.b12-0.el6_10.
After the upgrade we are started getting error **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**.
There is no code change in application and the linux box is same as it was there for Jboss 6.

We have analysed the heap dump shared by the production linux team. we used the JvisualVM and Eclipse Memory analyzer and it is pointing to below two possible leakage susspect.

**1. io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl**

**2. org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem**

Linux team has copied the same configuration from jBoss 6 to jBoss 7. The configuration is -

**export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xverify:none -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=com.sun.crypto.provider -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=1800000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=1800000 -server -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE=false -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/logs/EAP/"**

Increasing the heap space (young generation, eden storage) is the only option?

Comment: Analysing it further with DB team we have seen that as many as 200 database operation are in sleeping mode or in susspended mode. It seems database connection are not getting closed after we upgraded the Jboss and Spring jar. We have kept the Hibernate version as it is. The datasource set up is done in jboss standalone.xml file.

Comment: We increased the RAM in production server after that this issue is not coming anymore.